# How does mobile messenger work?

Tags: mobile, instantmessenger

As far I am concern, ebuddy manages all users accounts and when users connect to messenger service (both from websites and mobile phones), they in fact connect through ebuddy server (not directly).

Does EQO mobile messenger work in same way? Or we get connected directly from mobile to messenger server (yahoo,gtalk etc)?

Doesn't these sort of "connecting via another server" make our accounts vulnerable?

What are the free(or more preferably open source) mobile  messengers available for yahoo, gtalk,msn etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EQO works in nthe same way.
Yes, it makes your accounts vulnerable.
Palringo is a no-cost closed-source mobile IM client.
I don't know of an open-source mobile IM client.